# python struct.pack data have redundant 0

Tags: python, struct

I use this code pack data,

> data = struct.pack("bb3sb4si", 0x11, 3, 'abc', 4, 'kkkk', 0x12345678

and send it to my server.

But my server receive this

[image]

why i have the redundant double 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are implicity using [native alignment](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment); the extra bytes force the final integer to start on a 4-byte boundary. Disabling alignment with the `=` prefix removes the extra padding.

```
$ cat pack.py
import struct
import sys
data = struct.pack("=bb3sb4si", 0x11, 3, 'abc', 4, 'kkkk', 0x12345678)
sys.stdout.write(data)

$ python pack.py | xxd
0000000: 1103 6162 6304 6b6b 6b6b 7856 3412       ..abc.kkkkxV4.
```